# Trouble making object move in a circle

Tags: java, android, animation, bitmap, android-canvas

I'm new to animation in android. I'm working with a tutorial I have found on youtube. The app draws a picture of a ball on a canvas and then moves diagonally. I'd like to make the ball move in a circle. I've found some information about the basic math of circular motion but I'm having trouble implementing it. Could someone look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
public class DrawingTheBall extends View {

Bitmap bball; 
int x,y;

public DrawingTheBall(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    bball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blueball);
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Rect ourRect = new Rect();
    ourRect.set(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()/2);
    float a = 10;
    float b = 10;
    float r = 20;
    double theta = 0;
    theta = Math.toRadians(45);

    Paint blue = new Paint();
    blue.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    blue.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    canvas.drawRect(ourRect, blue);

    if(x < canvas.getWidth()){
        //x += 10;
        x = (int) (a +r*Math.cos(theta));
    }else{
        x = 0;
    }
    if(y < canvas.getHeight()){
        //y += 10;
        y = (int) (b +r*Math.sin(theta));
    }else{
        y = 0;
    }
    Paint p = new Paint();
    canvas.drawBitmap(bball, x, y, p);
    invalidate();
}
```

}

Comment: It looks correct though I believe that you should try changing around the cos and sin so x = (int)(a + r * Math.sin(100)) and y = (int)(b + r * Math.cos(100)) then increment the 100 value to have it continue to move in a circle

Comment: Don't think he will move on the circle when his coordinates are dependant on a constant angle, what he needs to do is increment the angle for every update. "a" and "b" only decide the center of the circle.

Answer (score 6):

Basically you need to use the Sine and Cosine trigonometric functions, which given the angle will give you the ratios of the corresponding x, and y coordinates on your screen.

something along:

```
double x = a + r * sin(angle);
double y = b + r * cos(angle);
```

should work.

where:

```
r - is the radius of the circle
(a,b) - is the center of the circle
angle - is the desired angle
```

Of course you need to increment the angle, in order for your object to move.

Answer (score 6):

Mathematically a point on the circle is defined by an angle `theta` and a distance from the center `radius`. In your code the angle is a constant `100` so it never moves on the circle. What you want to do is increase the angle in your update.

```
theta = theta + Math.toRadians(10);
x = a + r*Math.cos(theta);
y = b + r*Math.sin(theta);
```

This will let you move on a circle that centers on `(a,b)` with radius `r`, `10 degrees` at a time.

To your comment, add `theta` as a field and don't set it to `45` inside `onDraw`, if you want to start at 45 degrees you can initialize it to 45 inside your constructor.

```
int x,y; 
to
int x,y, theta;
```

To your comment

```
int x,y, theta;

public DrawingTheBall(Context context) {
    super(context);
    bball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blueball);
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    theta = 45;
}
```

And

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
super.onDraw(canvas);

Rect ourRect = new Rect();
ourRect.set(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()/2);
float a = 10;
float b = 10;
float r = 20;
//    double theta = 0;  //You are using a local variable that shadows the field, it starts at 0 everytime
 //   theta = Math.toRadians(45); //You are setting it to 45 degrees everytime, instead:
    theta = theta + Math.toRadians(10); //Increase of 10 degrees

Paint blue = new Paint();
blue.setColor(Color.BLUE);
blue.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

canvas.drawRect(ourRect, blue);

if(x < canvas.getWidth()){
    //x += 10;
    x = (int) (a +r*Math.cos(theta));
}else{
    x = 0;
}
if(y < canvas.getHeight()){
    //y += 10;
    y = (int) (b +r*Math.sin(theta));
}else{
    y = 0;
}
Paint p = new Paint();
canvas.drawBitmap(bball, x, y, p);
invalidate();
}
```

Comment: You might want to declare theta as theta = Math.toRadians(45); And secondly, you are using 55 degrees everytime (the variable is declared everytime onDraw is called and set to the same value) so you should set it as a field.

Comment: Where am I using 55? I switched to theta = Math.toRadians(45) but the it remains stationary. Also setting theta as a field of onDraw just made the ball not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post from another SO ticket, seems very similar.

[Android - Moving an object in circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708246/android-moving-an-object-in-circle)