# moving an object in a circle - android

Tags: java, android, animation, bitmap, android-canvas

I posted this question yesterday, I got some useful help but was unable to solve the problem. Just figured I'd keep trying.

Ok. I'm trying to make a ball move in a circle on a canvas in Android. After doing some research and reading a few similar questions - I think I got the logic down but the shape remains stationary. Basically I'm doing x = a +rcos(theta), y = rain(theta). I'm not really sure what the problem is. My code is below. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I've read the other questions and don't know why I can't make it work.

```
public class DrawingTheBall extends View {

Bitmap bball; 
int x,y, theta;


public DrawingTheBall(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    bball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blueball);
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    theta = 45;
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Rect ourRect = new Rect();
    ourRect.set(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()/2);
    float a = 10;
    float b = 10;
    float r = 20;

    theta = (int) Math.toRadians(10);


    Paint blue = new Paint();
    blue.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    blue.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    canvas.drawRect(ourRect, blue);

    if(x < canvas.getWidth()){

        x = (int) (a +r*Math.cos(theta));
    }else{
        x = 0;
    }
    if(y < canvas.getHeight()){

        y = (int) (b +r*Math.sin(theta));
    }else{
        y = 0;
    }
    Paint p = new Paint();
    canvas.drawBitmap(bball, x, y, p);
    invalidate();
}
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble making object move in a circle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802431/trouble-making-object-move-in-a-circle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to increment `theta` on the line:

```
theta = (int) Math.toRadians(10);
```

If you always draw at the same angle, you'll always draw to the same location.

EDIT:

You could place the above line in your constructor, and then in `onDraw`, you could do:

```
theta = (theta + 0.1) % (2 * Math.PI)
```

Comment: Increment? How should I do this? You mean like theta = 50 + (int)Math.toRadians(10)? or something like that.

Comment: So it depends on how you want to draw the circle. You could increment it every time onDraw is called with `theta = (theta + 0.1) % Math.PI`. Or you can have a button that modifies theta. I think you are misunderstanding how it is calculated. For now, assume that line reads `theta = 2.1`. Every time `onDraw` is called, theta will be 2.1 - which will always draw to the same location. That is what it is doing now.

Comment: @dave No problems - try not to repost and instead use bounties if you didn't get enough help with your original question (when you have enough rep :D).